# Face recognition in android?

Tags: android

I would like to do face detection in Android. I am aware of the `FaceDetector` API, which is not much mature. My requirement is to recognize a particular person in the db.

Can you suggest me some useful tips.

Comment: www.face.com will help U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no face recognition API which is a part of the Android SDK. The easiest thing to do would be to use an OpenCV android port ( http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) and implement a simple algorithm like PCA. The app FaceRecog PhoneLOCK  available for free in the android market ( https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vediket.facerecog ) does exactly that.